# How to get current time in a specific time zone in postgres Database

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get and compare current date time with multiple time zones in Postgres DB?

By using this query we can get different time zone times instanlty.

select now(), now() at time zone 'utc', now() at time zone 'est',now() at time zone 'edt'

Comment: You seemed to have answered your own question in the question by showing times at different time zones. If that is not the case you will need to be more specific about what you want to happen. Example code would be helpful. **Add as text update to question text**.

Comment: EST and EDT aren't timezone names, they're ambiguous abbreviations. It's just luck that EST doesn't correspond to multiple timezones. IST on the other hand can be Irish, India, Israel Standard Time. As the [AT TIME ZONE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) show, a timezone name is eg `America/Denver`